# Multi definition error with namespace call

Tags: c++, arduino, namespaces

I am trying to use the following namespace in my main .ino file but it gives me a 'multi definition' error for the Motor variable. I'm new to C++. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

.ino file

```
using namespace InitFlower;

void setup() {
}

Motor m(STEP_DELAY,A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2);

void loop() {
  SETUP(m); 
}
```

InitFlower.h

```
#ifndef InitFlower_h
#define InitFlower_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Motor.h"

namespace InitFlower {
  void SETUP(Motor m);
  Motor* localMotor;
}
#endif
```

InitFlower.cpp

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Motor.h"
#include "InitFlower.h"

using namespace InitFlower;

void InitFlower::SETUP(Motor m) {
  localMotor = &m;
  localMotor->toSetup_LED();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following in your header file:

```
Motor* localMotor;
```

to:
extern Motor* localMotor;

and then add the following to your source file:

```
namespace InitFlower {
  Motor* localMotor;
}
```